# How to assign IPs in server interfaces when connected to two similar routers

Tags: router, ipv4, interface, route-server

I need to connect two similar routers with the IPs `192.160.2.4/24`  and `192.160.2.6/24` (in the same `192.160.2.0/24` network) to 2 server interfaces (ports) in the same server as shown in the image.

[image]

However, I cannot understand how to assign the IPs to the server interfaces.

After some googling, I now think that the server interfaces are bonded into a single virtual interface, and a single IP is assigned by the server OS. But I am not sure how the traffic flow and ARP work here, and whether redundancy mechanism is used as well.

How would the traffic flow to and from the server in the DLL and Network layers? Any help would be appreciated to understand how this configuration works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations or protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

Network connections generally are usually *many to many* - the whole point for a network -, only rarely point to point. Nodes with the same subnet address need to be located in the same subnet.

192.160.2.4/24 and 192.160.2.6/24 are located in the same subnet, so they must be connected by a common switch & VLAN. When the server interfaces are bonded and you need two connections to distinct(!) subnets you need to unbond them and configure them separately and you must separate the router subnet.

Whether the server NICs are bonded or not, when connected to the same subnet, both routers need to be connected to this subnet as well. Then, which router is selected for an external IP depends on the local routing table and its metrics.

The server interfaces require unused IP addresses from the same 192.160.2.0/24 subnet as the routers, at least one when bonded and at least two when separate. By default, the server would try to reach either router through any of its interfaces.

For a layer 3 topology your chart might make sense (with unbonded server NICs and accordingly set routing table). Connecting this way on the physical layer (wiring) would be cumbersome at best.